# Linq to entities, How to select all columns and also select custom columns?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I need to be able to do this query in linq

```
select t1.*, t2.column1, t2.column2
from Table1 as t1 inner join Table2 as t2
Where t2.x = true
```

the main table we want to get all his columns and some other columns from other tables. Can this be done in linq?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
from element in t1
join otherElement in t2
on element.match equals otherElement.match
where t2.x == true
select new { 
             column1 = otherElement.column1, 
             column2 = otherElement.column2
             //add all the elements of t1 here
            }
```

A **join** clause takes two source sequences as input. The elements in each sequence must either be or contain a property that can be compared to a corresponding property in the other sequence.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx